# How do I generate an already rigged avatar in Blender?

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have downloaded a model from Turbo-squid of a Panda Bearand I added it into Blender. The Panda Bear came with it's own rig, however when I decided to go into *Object Data Properties* in *Object mode*, then *Rigify Generations*, the "Generate Rig" button just wouldn't work.

The only thing I tried was that I tried to append the Panda Bear .Blend file as a *mesh*.

Comment: The Generate Rig button only works for a Rigify metarig. Do you want to replace the existing rig with Rigify?

Comment: Thank you, so I guess that I can't use an already rigged character and animate it.

Comment: Also Yes, I replaced the rig manually, was there another way to replace it? By the way I used the Horse Rig.